# Two Styles for a text in the android button

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating the app which consists of Dial pad.

I want to use two strings in a single button.One is having one set of style and another one having another set of style in style.xml.

Is there any way to do this in XML.

I want the text in the button to be as follows

android:text= @style 2 @style abc

Comment: Why you are all giving negative points. Is there any problem with the question.?

Answer (score 2):

There are some complex ways to do this involving Spannables, but depending on what you want to do, you may be able to get away with Html.fromHtml() and am html-formatted string resource.

Comment: Thanks. But We use Html.fromHtml() in java coding. Is there any way to achieve that in XML itself.